# Pandas: How to assign the value to the first row of a group after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to assign the value to **the first row of a group** after groupby?

Input:

> ID Num
>  Aa 100
>  Bb 200
>  Cc 300
>  Bb 400
>  Aa 500

Output:

> ID Num Sum
>  Aa 100 600
>  Aa 500
>  Bb 200 600
>  Bb 400
>  Cc
> 300 300

Code:

```
base_df['Sum'] = base_df.groupby(['ID'])['Num'].transform('sum')
```

However, this code will assign the value 'Sum' to **every row** in the group:

My output:

> ID Num Sum
>  Aa 100 600
>  Aa 500 600
>  Bb 200 600
>  Bb 400
> 600
>  Cc 300 300

Answer (score 1):

You can assign using `duplicated`:

```
s = df.groupby(['ID'])['Num'].transform('sum')
df.loc[~df.duplicated("ID"), "Sum"] = s
print (df)

   ID  Num    Sum
0  Aa  100  600.0
1  Bb  200  600.0
2  Cc  300  300.0
3  Bb  400    NaN
4  Aa  500    NaN
```